# Python serial read fails for long period

Tags: python, performance, esp8266, pyserial

I am using an accelerometer sensor in Node MCU to get 300 samples per second and store it for a week. My code below fails after some minutes.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("COM5", 115200)
ser.flushInput()
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        i += 1
        print (i)
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        print(ser_bytes)
    except:
        print("Keyboard Interrupt")
        break
```

It failed after 4129 lines. I've attached the output
[image]

Comment: Any chance your sensor just isn’t sending more data?

Comment: Sensor is sending the data. Checked with Serial Monitor in Arduino IDE.
It's working in C.